# VisualVM can not start

Tags: java, putty, visualvm, x11

I have a remote Debian Squeeze server. I've installed Oracle JDK `1.7.0_07` manually and configured alternatives to every binary in `jdk/bin` path. Also i exported the global JAVA_HOME variable.

```
# java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
#
```

Server has Gnome on board and I'm connecting with putty and `X-Windows forwarding` enabled.
But when I'm trying to launch VisualVM with `jvisualvm` command I just get nothing with 5-10 sec pause:

```
# jvisualvm
#
```

And when I try to show help, I see an Exception:

```
# jvisualvm --help
Usage: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../lib/visualvm//platform/lib/nbexec {options} arguments

General options:
  --help                show this help
  --jdkhome <path>      path to Java(TM) 2 SDK, Standard Edition
  -J<jvm_option>        pass <jvm_option> to JVM

  --cp:p <classpath>    prepend <classpath> to classpath
  --cp:a <classpath>    append <classpath> to classpath
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.netbeans.core.startup.Splash$SplashComponent
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Splash.<init>(Splash.java:111)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Splash.getInstance(Splash.java:64)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.setStatusText(Main.java:47)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents.setStatusText(NbEvents.java:384)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents.logged(NbEvents.java:159)
        at org.netbeans.Events.log(Events.java:127)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.readInitial(ModuleList.java:129)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.readList(ModuleSystem.java:241)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.CLICoreBridge.usage(CLICoreBridge.java:69)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.showHelp(CLIHandler.java:125)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.checkHelp(CLIHandler.java:179)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:530)
        at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(CLIHandler.java:346)
        at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(MainImpl.java:151)
        at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(MainImpl.java:46)
        at org.netbeans.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

I [googled](http://java.net/projects/visualvm/lists/users/archive/2012-09/message/2) that exception and found out that the `libxtst-dev` library is missing, but I installed it previously.

So what is the problem, how can I figure out what is going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

- I'm working under root.
- I don't have other versions of JDK in the system, the default OpenJDK was removed with `apt-get purge`.
- My `CLASSPATH` system variable is empty, is it a problem?

**UPDATE2:**
`libXtst` is in `/usr/lib`

```
root@test:/usr/lib# ls -la /usr/lib | grep libXtst
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    26666 Июн 23  2010 libXtst.a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       16 Окт  7 01:18 libXtst.so -> libXtst.so.6.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       16 Окт  6 20:26 libXtst.so.6 -> libXtst.so.6.1.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    23616 Июн 23  2010 libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

`libXext` is also in `/usr/lib`

```
root@test:~# ls -la /usr/lib | grep libXext
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   118668 Июл 11  2010 libXext.a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       16 Окт  6 22:26 libXext.so -> libXext.so.6.4.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root       16 Май 21 13:42 libXext.so.6 -> libXext.so.6.4.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    74432 Июл 11  2010 libXext.so.6.4.0
root@test:~#
```

here is output for command `jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true`

```
root@test:~# jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>Log Session: Monday, October 8, 2012 10:48:32 PM MSK
>System Info:
  Product Version         = Java VisualVM
  Operating System        = Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 running on i386
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.7.0_07; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 23.3-b01; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_07-b10
  Java Home               = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = ru_RU (visualvm); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /root
  Current Directory       = /root
  User Directory          = /root/.visualvm/7u6
  Cache Directory         = /root/.visualvm/7u6/var/cache
  Installation            = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/visualvm
                            /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/profiler
                            /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/classes:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
  Application Classpath   = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/boot.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/dt.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/core/core.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/core_ja.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/core_zh_CN.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-startup.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/locale/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-startup_ja.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/locale/core_visualvm.jar:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/locale/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-startup_zh_CN.jar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: Unable to open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1846)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:77)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:203)
        at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:84)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**UPDATE 3**
I downloaded Java demos and tried to launch SwingSet2:

```
root@test:/tmp/jdk1.7.0_06# java -jar demo/jfc/SwingSet2/SwingSet2.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: unbale to open shared object file: no such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1846)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
        at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
        at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1648)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1670)
        at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:595)
```

**UPDATE 4**

finally my mistake was in the version of JDK, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you found the correct answer when you googled for the exception. libXtst.so.6 is missing, it should be in /usr/lib directory. Are you sure that it is installed? Can you run any other Java GUI application like SwingSet2? Can you run VisualVM with -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true and post the output?

```
jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true
```

Comment: I added the info you asked in the original question. I don't know where to get `SwingSet2`, seems like it is a standard example but somehow it is not included in my JDK...

Comment: I found SwingSet2 and tried to launch it, and got the same error. So my configuration is definately broken, but where? How does JVM know where to look for Shared Libraries?

Comment: I think that the problem is somewhere else. From the log file it looks like you are running 32bit JDK 1.7.0_07 on 64bit system and you are missing some 32bit libraries. I suggest to download and install 64bit JDK 1.7.0_07 and use it instead of 32bit one.

Comment: Yes, man! My mistake was that I installed the wrong version of JDK.  Everything starts and works great with the 64-bit one! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Resolution for MAC: [In my case nothing was happening when I was trying to open the app]

Goto Application folder, Show Contents -> Resources/visualvm/etc/visualvm.conf

Example:

/Applications/VisualVM.app/Contents/Resources/visualvm/etc/visualvm.conf

Uncomment "visualvm_jdkhome" and replace the value with the correct JDK home path.

Example:

visualvm_jdkhome="/Users/username/tools/jdk-11.0.10.jdk/Contents/Home"

Try opening the app again, It should open.